# Create a string and append text to it

Tags: vb.net

Funny, I had a textbox and I could append strings to it.

But now I create a string like this:

```
    Dim str As String = New String("")
```

And I want to append to it other strings. But there is no function for doing so. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Concatenate with & operator**

```
Dim str as String  'no need to create a string instance
str = "Hello " & "World"
```

*You can concate with the + operator as well but you can get yourself into trouble when trying to concatenate numbers.*

**Concatenate with [String.Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1.aspx)**

```
str = String.Concat("Hello ", "World")
```

*Useful when concatenating array of strings*

**StringBuilder.Append()**

When concatenating large amounts of strings use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), it will result in much better performance.

```
    Dim sb as new System.Text.StringBuilder()
    str = sb.Append("Hello").Append(" ").Append("World").ToString()
```

Strings in .NET are immutable, resulting in a new String object being instantiated for every concatenation as well a garbage collection thereof.

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do this is to add the new characters to the string as follows:

```
Dim str As String

str = ""
```

To append text to your string this way:

```
str = str & "and this is more text"
```

Comment: This is the only answer replying the question

Answer (score 7):

Use the string concatenation operator:

```
Dim str As String = New String("") & "some other string"
```

Strings in .NET are immutable and thus there exist no concept of appending strings. All string modifications causes a new string to be created and returned.

This obviously cause a terrible performance. In common everyday code this isn't an issue, but if you're doing intensive string operations in which time is of the essence then you will benefit from looking into the StringBuilder class. It allow you to queue appends. Once you're done appending you can ask it to actually perform all the queued operations.

See ["How to: Concatenate Multiple Strings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) for more information on both methods.