# How can I add a "code" inside of a string?

Tags: vb.net, quotes

So, here's the code I want to be in string :

```
TEAM_SUPERADMIN = DarkRP.createJob("Superadmin on Duty", {
color = Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
model = {"models/player/group01/male_01.mdl"},
description = [[This is the Superadmin on Duty job!]],
weapons = {"weapon_fists", "unarrest_stick"},
command = "superadmin",
max = 5,
salary = 45,
admin = 0,
vote = false,
hasLicense = false,
})
```

My attempt to put this into a text box was this:

```
TextBox14.Text = "TEAM_SUPERADMIN = DarkRP.createJob("Superadmin on Duty", {
color = Color(0, 0, 0, 255),
model = {"models/player/group01/male_01.mdl"},
description = [[This is the Superadmin on Duty job!]],
weapons = {"weapon_fists", "unarrest_stick"},
command = "superadmin",
max = 5,
salary = 45,
admin = 0,
vote = false,
hasLicense = false,
})"
```

But it thought the string I was the text inside the first two quotes. Please help!

Comment: You need to escape the quotes from your "code".  Not sure how do to that in VB.Net.  In C# you would use \".

Comment: Well, here's a SC of the form : http://prntscr.com/76sme6 . Basically what I want it to do is they enter what the want, and it enters each one where I want it to go. Similar to the site : http://www.thecodingbeast.com/tools?id=job . Also, when it's generated, it'll show in the textbox at the bottom.

Comment: I would set each element as a variable then populate together for your textbox. You could use an array with 13 elements if you prefer but it would make it more difficult to keep track of what each element is as opposed to nicely named variables ie strTeamID, strName, strColor etc etc

Answer (score 2):

Every place you want quotes you'll need double quotes.  ""Superadmin on Duty""

If you're going to have the string on multiple lines, you need to have line continuation.  Close the string and then put a _ at the end of the line.  Then start the next line with `& "more stuff..."`

So the first couple of lines would look like:

```
TextBox14.Text = "TEAM_SUPERADMIN = DarkRP.createJob(""Superadmin on Duty"", {" & VbCrLf _
    & "color = Color(0, 0, 0, 255)," & VbCrLf _
```

There are several other ways to do this as well.  You can use the += to just keep adding text to a variable or control:

```
TextBox14.Text = "TEAM_SUPERADMIN = DarkRP.createJob(""Superadmin on Duty"", {" & VbCrLf
TextBox14.Text += "color = Color(0, 0, 0, 255)," & VbCrLf
TextBox14.Text += "..."
```

Numerous ways you can concatenate a string in a variable, and then assign the control's text to the contents of the variable.  See [Create a string and append text to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360303/create-a-string-and-append-text-to-it).

Comment: But then it finds the commas and ends the string.

Comment: Don't replace the first and last one

Comment: I didn't know about double double quotes for a long time and I used `& chr(34) &` every time I needed a double quote in a string.  :(

Answer (score 2):

replace double quotes with double double quotes within the string and build the string with caraige returns:

```
TextBox14.Text = "TEAM_SUPERADMIN = DarkRP.createJob(""Superadmin on Duty"", {" _
& vbLf & "color = Color(0, 0, 0, 255)," _
& vbLf & "model = {""models/player/group01/male_01.mdl""}," _
& vbLf & "description = [[This is the Superadmin on Duty job!]]," _
& vbLf & "weapons = {""weapon_fists"", ""unarrest_stick""}," _
& vbLf & "command = ""superadmin""," _
& vbLf & "max = 5," _
& vbLf & "salary = 45," _
& vbLf & "admin = 0," _
& vbLf & "vote = false," _
& vbLf & "hasLicense = false," _
& vbLf & "})"
```

Note the space after the underscore, I just tested with this and it works:

```
MsgBox("TEAM_SUPERADMIN = DarkRP.createJob(""Superadmin on Duty"", {" _
& vbLf & "color = Color(0, 0, 0, 255)," _
& vbLf & "model = {""models/player/group01/male_01.mdl""}," _
& vbLf & "description = [[This is the Superadmin on Duty job!]]," _
& vbLf & "weapons = {""weapon_fists"", ""unarrest_stick""}," _
& vbLf & "command = ""superadmin""," _
& vbLf & "max = 5," _
& vbLf & "salary = 45," _
& vbLf & "admin = 0," _
& vbLf & "vote = false," _
& vbLf & "hasLicense = false," _
& vbLf & "})")
```

You can see the difference on the SO forum as it formats text as red (Look at your code compared to mine)

Comment: I'ved tried that. It picks up the commas though and ends the string.

Comment: Note I just replace CHR(13) with vbLf which is a better way to do it. I just wasn't sure if that was a VBA or a VB in general thing :)

Comment: I'm getting errors on MyString when I make it all a dim except for the last line

Comment: Can I actually explain my goal of this windows form is? Will that make it easier for you guys? Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: Yes definitely, the more criteria you give us, the easier it will be to help.

Comment: Yes! That works, but how could I make it so it copies to their clipboard or make it able to be copied?

Comment: This is how you copy something to the clipboard:

Clipboard.Clear()

Clipboard.SetText("Put This Text In Clipboard")

Make sure you have Imports System.Text at the top of your code

Comment: When I use this, how could I replace something with the text the entered?

Comment: What are the objects called where they enter the text?

Answer (score -1):

I would hazard a guess that you may want to save more than one block of code.

And if you use any of the other approaches you will have HARD CODE by hand each code block.

Therefore it makes sense to develop a subroutine to do the donkey work for you!

Something along the lines of...

```
Function Stringify(ByVal Textdata As String) As String
  '
  Dim buf As String
  Dim counta As Integer
  '
  buf = ""
  For counta = 1 To Len(Textdata)
    If Mid(Textdata, counta, 1) = Chr(34) Then
      buf = buf & """ & chr(34) & """
    Else
      buf = buf & Mid(Textdata, counta, 1)
    End If
  Next
  Stringify = Chr(34) & buf & Chr(34)
  '
End Function
```

And you would call the function as....

```
MyConvertedCodeString = Stringify(txtTextData.text)
```

Comment: Have the courtesy to comment the reason for down posting my efforts to help another SO member. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You Christian - Me neither, but I could understand if there was a flaw in my code and it was pointed out to me. Anyway good luck with your project buddy.