# End of Statement Expected in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm creating a full name generator.
In the second line at `txtFirstName.Text` it shows up with the error

> end of statement expected.

Does anyone know why?

```
Private Sub btnDisplayName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayName.Click
    lblFullName.Text = "Hello, " txtFirstName.Text txtLastName.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Missing string concatenation operator : "xxxxxx" & "more text"

Comment: You have two options. Either `"Hello, " & txtFirstName.Text & txtLastName.Text` as suggested by fnostro above or using [Interpolated Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/special-characters/interpolated): `$"Hello, {txtFirstName.Text} {txtLastName.Text}"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a string and append text to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360303/create-a-string-and-append-text-to-it)

Comment: Also see : [& Operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator)

Answer (score 4):

you forgot `&` :

```
Private Sub btnDisplayName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayName.Click
    lblFullName.Text = "Hello, "  & txtFirstName.Text & txtLastName.Text
End Sub
```